# Save instance of a class module in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, save, instance

I have a project for my Excel file, it's something like a project with branch on git.

I have a main object :

```
Private member1 as String
Private member2 as String
Private list as Collection

Public Sub Initialize()
'Some code
End sub

Public sub Foo()
'Some code
End sub
```

each item in the member "list" was another Collection.
And each items in this another collection was another collection with Instance of a class module

```
Private member1 As String
Private member2 As collection
Private member3 As collection
Private member4 As Integer
Private member5 As String
Private member6 As Statut_Enum

Sub foo()
'Some code
end Sub
```

Basically we have :

```
Main object : 
  Member1
  Member2
  List:
    SubList1:
      SubSubList1:
        instanceOfClassModule1
        instanceOfClassModule2
      SubSubList2:
        instanceOfClassModule1
        instanceOfClassModule2
    SubList2
      SubSubList1:
        instanceOfClassModule1
        instanceOfClassModule2
```

I'm looking to a way for save the entire instance of the main object with sub Collection/object in a file, for load the next time i open the Excel File

I don't know if it's possible to do this or if I need to create myself a Write/Load function

Thank's

Comment: Could you explain why you need to save the main object instance?  There may be other solutions which don't require saving.

Comment: Save to json and parse it on load. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @freeflow Well, basically each instance of class module represent a line in a sheet. each SubSubList represent a sheet. Each subList group a specific template of SubSublist/Instances

I thinking about save the main object for have something like "All in a file" but i'm open to all Solutions

Comment: You mean a physical Excel-sheet?

Comment: Yes, every sheet have an array  where each line have members value of an instance, but i need array with different specifications,
is like a git project where the main object is the main branch, and each item on the list was another branch based on main branch but with some specification.

Comment: If the project is self-contained in a single Excel file, create a "hidden" sheet and save your entire instance data there. This guarantees the data is always included in the workbook and you don't have to open an external file. JSON or other external storage options are fine if your application requires multiple and/or a changeable number of Excel files. The instance data on the hidden sheet is easily pulled into collections or memory-based arrays.

Comment: I have think about that, but the file grow up and can have 40-50 sheets different
I don't really know how save 40 x 19 instances in one hidden file